# Writing 'partition' Failed (remote failure) error, when flashing from fastboot

Tags: fastboot, system-error, motorola-droid-razr

A couple of days ago, I got an error on my phone (Motorola Razr HD xt925) saying that it cannot load the home screen. So, I restarted it in order to resolve the issue. However, it didn't reboot and since then it has been stuck in the Motorola logo.

- I tried to do recovery or factory reset, but all the options lead to the same Motorola logo with no luck.
- The only option that is working is **AP Fastboot**.  I managed to unlock the bootloader by getting an unlock code from Motorola's website and using the **mfastboot** command. So I assume that the fastboot command is working since it detects the devices; however, I couldn't make ADB command to work since it give the error: 'device not found'.
- Anyway, the second step is to flash the phone. According to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73374/moto-x-rooting-rom-doesnt-boot-but-have-safestrap), I should be able to do that. However, when I am running the command `fastboot flash partition gpt.bin`, I am getting the following result:

  ```
  (bootloader) Variable not supported!
  target max-download-size: 30MB
  sending 'partition' (32 KB)...
  OKAY [  0.022s]
  writing 'partition'...
  FAILED (remote failure)
  finished. total time: 0.154s
  ```

I have been searching for days to solve this problem, but nothing yet! I don't know which part I am doing wrong.

Comment: I just want to verify that there nothing else in the command prompt and the word error  was not present followed by a reason? Another issue is when at the Motorola website the **mfastboot** command was use. At the second step running the command **fastboot flash partition gpt.bin**  is that correct? What was the file name of the mfastboot software and where did you get it? What type of PC  are you using? did  you set a path? Which command prompt did you use? Did you run it with elevated privileges? Oh and what version of android did you have before the crash? That s

Comment: 1) Have you made sure that [this - low battery](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/2blj7h/moto_g_remote_failure/cj7vmoi) is not the case? 2) Is the bootloader unlocked? 3) Could you consider flashing only a custom recovery using fastboot? We can then flash a zip file from Recovery mode.

Comment: @BoLawson: mfastboot is same as fastboot but for Motorola phone. I found it at xda-developers.com and also at sbf.droid-developers.org. I have tried both on Windows and Linux machines with elevated privileges. The android version was originally v4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) but I had upgraded it to v4.4.2 (KitKat) using OTA.

Comment: @Firelord: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) How should I do that? Sorry for asking, but I am a newbie here!

Comment: I'm assuming that you've not messed up your system yet. In that case, try erasing userdata and cache first. Do `fastboot erase cache` then `fastboot erase userdata`. Report any error here. Reboot and tell us the result. // Otherwise, find a custom Recovery for your device like TWRP, and flash it as `fastboot flash recovery <YOUR_FILE>.img`. Now power-off and reboot into recovery mode using button combinations. Tell us the results then.

Comment: @Firelord: running the command `fastboot erase cashe` gives this error: 
`(bootloader) Variable not supported!
erasing 'cache'...
(bootloader) Failed to erase partition
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.047s`

Comment: Looks like we need to Google more. Try that custom Recovery stuff I said in the last comment, though success seems to be slim.

Comment: I have also tried it. No luck! Do you know what would be the problem?

Comment: This would sound strange but is it  confirmed that the bootloader is unlocked? Post the output of  `fastboot getvar all`.

Comment: `(bootloader) unlocked: yes

(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: yes`

Comment: What was the file name you were trying to flash?  Also file name for the fastboot? The thing is you can't downgrade android versions with bootloader Motorola uses It has to be the same or higher. Different variants use different software and can be carrier specific. As far as fastboot to mfastboot the protocol  is slightly different sometimes one will fail when the other does not.

Comment: Lets say I just want to run `fastboot erase cache` to erase the cache. Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Sina, just give that `mfastboot` thing a try for the purpose of trying since we don't have any lead as of now. At least @BoLawson's concerns can be resolved in that way. Also, I remember that somewhere somebody said the same thing to use that `mfastboot`, though it's odd to think why it would be any different from `fastboot`.

Comment: this is what's going on sorry I should  mentioned it earlier. There are  checks the system  does and some of them android are verified. If everything is as stated in post then without the error. the process was aborted before it begins because and failure to pass those checks. Things that can cause it outdated version of fastboot, drivers, multiple copies of a program creating issues with the path variable. If unrooted then it has to be official firmware from manufacturer. The wrong variant firmware sometimes can cause this or the bootloader thing not being able to downgrade and so on.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I had exactly the same issue earlier this year (albeit with a first gen Moto G), and I ended up having to buy a new phone because I tried absolutely everything, even erasing partitions gets you a `remote failure`

Comment: No I couldn't manage to solve the problem. I also bought a new phone and my old phone is still in my closet waiting to be rescued!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Motorola root toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2154995).
From [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2427667), give a try to mfastboot-v2, then post your results.

Comment: the tool kit is not working on my windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This step is not necessary just leave it and continue other steps if more steps fails then you should use your lastly updated ROM version... You can't flash lollipop ROM on marshmallow bootloader...flash stock marshmallow ROM or your current rom using mfastboot v2...

Answer (score 0):

The Remote failure is simply causing for flashing an old/incompatible gpt.bin file.